# create report of datagrid in c# with custom column and custom order

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

i have a datagrid in wpf
End users can reorder columns or hide some and then print data,
i want to create report with visible columns in order of each one ,
what is your idea?
is any way to implement that in stimulsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to create a report at run-time and show it.
You could find a sample [on GitHub](https://github.com/stimulsoft/Samples-WPF-CSharp/tree/master/Runtime%20Report%20Creation)